# Is running my own apps on a real phone safe?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I am a newbie to android programming and i am trying to write a few applications. The ones i wrote are working fine on an emulator.However i am afraid  to test it on my physical device. Is doing so safe? I mean the apps could have some unnoticed bug such as a MediaPlayer object not being released or something that may slow down my phone. Should I test it on my phone regardless of these risks?

Comment: You must test your app in real Physical Device. If you want how your app acting in real device.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. You run more risks installing someone else's app (since you can't steal your own private information...)

On any modern operating system, including Android, there are guards built into the operating system to prevent bad code or failure conditions from causing damage. The Dalvik VM extends these protections with memory checks, and the like. Unless you try **very** hard to write **actual** malware, you will not cause damage. Even if you enter a tight loop of some sort, the phone will manage CPU power to keep critical kernel elements running, and adjust clock speeds so any reasonable phone would be safe.

At the filesystem level, apps have very restricted write permissions so you cannot really risk overwriting system files unless there was already an issue in Android, which is a bigger issue in its entirety. You could try to stuff the memory with files, but they can be deleted by uninstalling the application.

An additional argument for using a physical device is that it is the only way to truly test an app. Emulator environments are nice, but how will your app work with other apps alongside, noisy sensors, screen rotation, network packet loss, etc?

There were only true risks on DOS-like or Windows 3.1-like machines where there was no protected memory. For example, bad code could overwrite filesystem buffers and cause massive issues.

Answer (score 2):

You should. In worst case scenario (which I'm pretty sure you can't get in) you just restart your phone.